# Is it possible to install a HP Deskjet 930C series printer in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, installation, printer

I want to install my HP Deskjet 930C printer in a notebook with Windows 8.1. I'm not familiar with Windows 8.1, but AFAIK the process to install is the same - Control Panel, Devices and Printer, Add a New Printer, locate it, etc..

The problem is that the noteobok is being incapable of detecting the printer. I remember when I tried (succesffully) to install it in my Windows 7 I had to do some tricky things, since the printer is quite old, including (if I'm not mistaken) donwloading and installing a specific driver for it. But doing some research on the web I simply coulnd't find anything for Windows 8 (including in HP's website). And when I ask Windows 8 to install the printer manually, it is not even listed among the available ones!

So is it my only my impression or it isn't possible to install HP Deskjet 930C printer on my Windows 8.1 (because it is to old)? If it is possible, then how should I do it since I can't find a driver for it, locate it on the network (it is hosted on another computer) and Windows 8.1 don't have it included on the printers list?

Answer (score 0):

Well at the end everything went fine.

The answer is **yes**, it is possible. I did it by opening Explorer and the section "Network" (or "Connections", I'm not sure; my Windows 8.1 is in Portuguese). Previously it didn't show, but now the PC where the printer was hosted was there. I clicked on it and the icon to the printer was there. So it was just a matter of right-clicking on the icon and clicking in the menu option "Connect" and Windows did the rest.